# Powershell output doesn't log properly when called from Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, powershell, azure, scheduled-tasks, taskscheduler

I need to log my powershell output. My ps file is something like this:

```
#Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
$ErrorActionPreference="SilentlyContinue"
Stop-Transcript | out-null
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
$date = (Get-Date).tostring("MMddyy HHmmss")
$filename = 'C:\apierror\logs\' + $date + '.txt'
Start-Transcript -path $filename -append

$python = "C:\Python34\python.exe"

$python_path = "C:\script.py"

cd (split-path $python_path)

& $python $python_path

Stop-Transcript
```

Now, when I run this file directly from powershell, the output is logged correctly. But when I try to run it from taskscheduler - only some portion of the console output is stored in the file.

Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: I am too having the same issue. If you have achieved solving this via Powershell please share your working

Answer (score 0):

Using transcript only stored partial output for some reason. I ended up using logs directly into the python file as opposed to powershell. Seems to be working correctly.